# Scala how to fix type erasure warning even though I added ClassTag

Tags: scala, type-erasure, scala-reflect

I am wondering how to fix the type erasure warning even though I added `ClassTag`? is there an easy fix without adding an additional library like TypeTag?

```
import scala.reflect.ClassTag

class Node
class C_PHYLUM[T]
class I_PHYLUM[T](name: String)
trait C_SEQUENCE[T1,T2]
class T_SEQUENCE[T]

class M_SEQUENCE[T_ElemType <: Node : ClassTag](name : String, t_ElemType:C_PHYLUM[T_ElemType])
  extends I_PHYLUM[T_SEQUENCE[T_ElemType]](name)
    with C_SEQUENCE[T_SEQUENCE[T_ElemType],T_ElemType]
{
  type T_Result = T_SEQUENCE[T_ElemType];
  def u__op_AC(x:Any) : Option[(T_Result,Seq[T_ElemType])] = x match {
    case x : T_Result => Some((x,toList(x)));
    case _ => None
  };

  def toList[T](x: T): Seq[T_ElemType] = Seq(x.asInstanceOf[T_ElemType])
}
```

Warning:

```
warning: abstract type T_ElemType in type pattern T_SEQUENCE[T_ElemType] (the underlying of M_SEQUENCE.this.T_Result) is unchecked since it is eliminated by erasure
    case x : T_Result => Some((x,toList(x)));
```

[Re-producable example](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/Wa4n2t4bSlSLiwNkElCX9w)

Comment: In short, it's because you only have ClassTag for `T_ElementTyoe`, not `T_SEQUENCE[T_ElemType]`. They are different types. There are a few solutions but you likely need to store the ClassTag inside `T_SEQUENCE` class

Comment: Also, please, use Scala naming convention when coding in Scala

Comment: @cchantep this an auto-generated scala code. Not a handwritten code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Type erasure is a consequence of how generics are implemented on the JVM. It means that a runtime, you won't be able to tell the difference between e.g. a `List[Int]` and a `List[String]`; all the runtime knows is that you have a `List`. The knowledge of whether you're expecting `[Int]` or `[String]` is compile-time only.

In your case, you have `T_SEQUENCE[T_ElemType]` - so given some object of type `Any`, you can use `isInstanceOf` to check if you have an instance of some `T_SEQUENCE`, but there's no knowledge of what the type parameter on it is.

You could make an assumption that your method will never receive a `T_SEQUENCE` with the wrong type parameter, and use that to do

```scala
case x : T_SEQUENCE[_] => Some((x.asInstanceOf[T_Result],toList(x.asInstanceOf[T_Result])))
```

Or, assuming your `T_SEQUENCE` class has some kind of `.map` method that lets you transform the value inside, you could do something that delegates to the `ClassTag` that you brought in, e.g.

```scala
// I'll assume a method like this exists:
def transformTSeq[A, B](tSeq: T_SEQUENCE[A], f: A => Option[B]): Option[T_SEQUENCE[B]]

// inside your match
case x: T_SEQUENCE[_] =>
  transformTSeq(x, value => {
    implicitly[ClassTag[T_ElemType]].unapply(value)
  })
case _ => 
  None
```

P.S. get rid of those semicolons

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. Is there a better solution that uses ClassTag or TypeTag? this is an autogenerated scala code and I want to make a minimal change.

Comment: TypeTag and ClassTag are both ultimately just tools that help you use reflection at runtime, so both will be subject to the limitations of type erasure. What I showed are the two best solutions I'm aware of; you just have to choose one based on the needs of your program.